# How to join split words?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text, for example:

```
Users of MW many times com-
plain that...
```

And I want to join the word:

```
Users of MW many times complain that...
```

I tried this:

```
value.replace(/[a-zA-Z][-]((\r\n)|(\n))/g, '')
```

but this solution replaces also a letter before '-'.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a word boundary before the hyphen at the end of the line and  then match 0 or more whitespace symbols:

```js
var s = "Users of MW many times com-\nplain that...";
document.write(s.replace(/\b-$\s*/gm, ''));
```

The word boundary checks if the hyphen is preceded with a word character.
Due to `/m` modifier `$` matches the end of a line. `\s*` matches 0 or more whitespace symbols.

Another option is to match a letter and capture it and restore later in the replacement with the help of a `$1` back-reference:

```js
var s = "Users of MW many times com-\nplain that...";
document.write(s.replace(/([a-z])-$\s*/igm, '$1'));
```

Here, `/i` is also used to enable case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the section: '[a-zA-Z]'.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
value.replace(/([a-zA-Z])[-]((\r\n)|(\n))/g, '$1')
```

Comment: `-` is not a special character, you don't need to enclose it between square brackets or to escape it. When you want to group things in a pattern without to capture them, use a non-capturing group : `(?:...)`. Instead of using this alternation `\r\n|\n`, make the CR optional: `\r?\n`

Comment: You are right, of course, but I wanted to change as little as possible in the original, especially if it is not wrong *per se* just redundant/inelegant. And furthermore: not all people like Appple ;-)